# Best storage and organisation approach IOS app

Tags: ios

I'm building an IOS app (native) where a number of football teams are presented on the screen for the user to select a favourite. Whats the best approach for storing / building these team objects in the app.

One possibility would be to collect all the teams from an API and store them in some kind of IOS storage / database component, however the teams will rarely change so it seems over kill. Another option is just to hard code it by creating each team in something like the app delegate or storing them in a plist.

Secondly each team will have images associated with them e.g. badge, players etc. Whats the best way to organise these image assets. From what I can see images can be grouped into folders in images.xassets however those folders are ignored when calling the image from code.

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"badge"];
```

Which would be a problem since each team would have an image named badge. Should I prepend the image name with the corresponding team name or is there a better way to link and organise these assets to a given team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look into sqlite data base with [CoreData](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) interface. You can organize perfectly well what you need. It also allows for image storage. If you've never worked with it, it migth be difficult at the beginning, but after the learning curve you'll find it really useful.